# How do you create a tapered multi stroke

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, draw-mode

Sorry if this question doesn't make any sense, let me explain,

So, in blender grease pen, you have a multi stroke modifier. When you draw, the beginning point and end point are the same width.

I wish it was more like the beginning was pointier and thinner and eases to thicker in the middle and then thinner and pointier at the end, that is applied to the entire multi stroke, not to individual strokes.
Is this possible?

I hope that makes sense.